# How to get differentiate between autocompletion and text entering

Tags: winapi, autocomplete

ALL,
Is it possible to differentiate between selecting the string in the autocompletion list or by just typing the string from keyboard?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to differentiate?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, because I am interested only in the complete string. What I want is to catch the "Enter" press in the list or mouse click there and display more data when it happens. I don't really care about intermediate selections.

Comment: Have you tried subclassing the list directly so you can intercept mouse/keyboard messages that are sent to it?